# Change table height according to td

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a table in td

```
<td style="height:100%">
   <table>

   <table>
<td>
```

The td is not fixed, it is of variable height, i want to set the table height according to the td.

Please provide your valuable suggetions to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a static code which works:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
 <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td height="100px">
        <table border="1" height="100px">
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <tr>
                <td>1.2</td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td height="100px">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am working to make it as dynamic as possible.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just setting the height of the table work as you've done for the td?

```
<td style="height:100%;">
   <table style="height:100%;">

   <table>
<td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your nested table don't have inside this:

```
<tr><td>content</td></tr>
```

Get an example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gsubiran/Xe3Gp/)